# For what integers n is the group S_n generated by an element of order 2 together with an element of order 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

As the question title suggests, for what integers $n$ is the group $S_n$ generated by an element of order $2$ together with an element of order $3$?

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to asking which $S_n$ appear as a quotient of the modular group $\Gamma = PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf, all values
of $n$ except 2, 5, 6, 8. The result is old, going back to Miller in 1901.

Comment: Theorem 2.7 in that pdf.